# Cannot migrate Oracle database (initially create tables) because of insufficient privileges?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to Oracle DB and really not sure what kind of privileges I should setup for an user so that they can execute basic commands like create,drop,delete, insert, update, select tables.

And I've setup all those privileges for my user account. But when running migrate, it failed with the following error printed in console window:

> 2019-05-27 08:29:07.837809 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues) Failed executing DbCommand (292ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0'] BEGIN  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOMER" ( "Id" NUMBER(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, ... )'; END; 2019-05-27 08:29:07.842817 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at line 2 at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone) at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF) at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
> ORA-06512: at line 2

So looks like the involved SQL command here is `BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE …`. I'm not so sure what kind of privileges I should setup for that to be executed successfully. Based on the error info above, how can I set up the privileges correctly for my user account?

PS: screenshots showing all privileges I've setup:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `BEGIN  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '***CREATE TABLE***...`

Comment: @T.S. what do you mean by that comment? the command there is auto-generated while migrating using `update-database`, it's out of my control.

Comment: I basically says there to you  - insufficient privileges to `create table`

Comment: @T.S. But as you can see my screens hots, isn't that create table privilege granted? Also actually it run and produced a lot of logs (looks like it succeeded partially) but failed at that command, really I'm not sure why it doesn't use 'create table' directly but via 'execute immediate'? That really requires another kind of privilege that I've not known of and 'create table' is not enough

Comment: I don't know a tool you use. 

Screenshots contain the "is role" set to "yes". If your user acquired those privileges via some role, try to grant them directly as they won't work in named PL/SQL procedures. What you posted, though, looks like an anonymous PL/SQL block, so - maybe that isn't the reason.

Why does it use dynamic SQL (i.e. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`)? Because - in PL/SQL - you can't execute DDL otherwise.

Comment: @Littlefoot I'm using Enterprise manager provided by Oracle, at least in sql server we can execute some command like 'create table' directly, hence my wondering. Actually the migration successfully created a table named __MigrationHistory so I think the privilege for creating table is already granted (before it was failed for another error and I added the privilege (as you can see in the screenshots) and it worked but running the 'update-database' produced the error I've posted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: I guess, what *littlefoot* is saying, in Oracle, you can execute DDL in editor but not within executable block. This is why you have `execute immediate`, because your code is between `Begin-End`

Comment: thank you all for your comments, I've found the answer after nearly one day forgetting about it and sometimes coming back to struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like that the `CREATE TABLE` privilege is fine only when the table to be created does not contain any auto-incremented primary key?

It's really not enough in my case and I've tried adding 2 more privileges (for sure but not really know if which one does the trick or both do): `CREATE CLUSTER` and `CREATE SEQUENCE`.
Looks like when creating my tables, it need to create some sequence first (for identity columns) or create cluster for primary key ...

Actually I just tried looking in the `RESOURCE` role for any possible privileges that are missing for my specific user and I found the 2 most possible privileges as mentioned above.

It now works fine, all tables can be created fine :) blocking me about 1 day (of course not always focusing on it, but really waiting and thinking about the cause).